# clarification about Android documentation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

> Note: Even if the system destroys your activity while it's stopped, it still retains the state
>
> of the View objects (such as text in an EditText) in a Bundle (a blob
> of key-value pairs) and restores them if the user navigates back to
> **the same instance of the activity** (the next lesson talks more about
> using a Bundle to save other state data in case your activity is
> destroyed and recreated).

**the same instance of the activity**

how it could be exact instance when it is destroyed and recreated , isn't it going to be a new memory block (another instance ), could anyone help me to clear this point ?

Comment: sounds to be like its being destroyed and recreated, theoretically if the new instance is created at the same memory block then old pointers  are still pointing to the same instance. IMHO. i am not an expert in the android memory model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the documentation isn't very clear in a lot of areas. This is one of them.

In theory, if Android were to destroy your activity while it is stopped, then it would call `onDestroy()` and the GC would reclaim the memory. In actual fact, Android never destroys individual activities to free up memory. What it actually does is it **kills the entire OS process** instead. In this case, `onDestroy()` never gets called on any of the activities in the process. The GC doesn't bother to clean up anything, because the VM (Virtual Machine) just dies immediately along with everything else in the process and the entire amount of memory in use by the process is reclaimed by the operating system.

When your user navigates back to your application, Android creates a completely new process for your application and then it will create a **new instance** of your activity. In this case it will, of course, get a completely new block of memory for the instance. You will also see the constructor get called and `onCreate()` will also be called. However, since Android saves the state of the activity's views, that state will be restored by the activity by the call to `super.onCreate()`.

There are a few cases where Android will destroy an instance of an activity and create a new one automatically. This is done, for example, during a configuration (ie: orientation) change. In that case, Android calls `onDestroy()` on the old instance and creates a new instance of the activity. The new instance gets the saved state of the old instance and can therefore restore the state of the views as able. In this case, since a new instance is being created, it will, of course, have a different address in memory.

Once a component is **destroyed**, it is effectively dead and the memory it is using can be reclaimed by the GC. Android will never **reanimate** a dead instance.

Hopefully this clarifies the situation for you.

**EDIT Add more details**

Android keeps track of tasks and the activities in those tasks in its own internal data structures. For each activity, it keeps a copy of the `Intent` that started the activity, the most recent `Intent` sent to that activity and it keeps a `Bundle` containing the saved state of that activity. Android calls `onSaveInstanceState()` on an activity to give the activity a chance to save anything that it will need to restore the activity if Android decides to kill it. The default implementation of `onSaveInstanceState()` saves the state of all the activity's views. Your implementation needs to save anything else that the activity will need to restore itself if it is killed and recreated by Android (for whatever reason). Your activity's private member variables and static variables are **not automatically saved and restored in the `Bundle`**, so if you need these to be able to recreate your activity properly you must save them yourself using the `Bundle` provided by `onSaveInstanceState()`. Static variables will stay around for the lifetime of the application's process, but since Android can kill the process (to reclaim resources) at any time, without warning, you also cannot rely on static variables always having the expected values (in the case where Android has killed and recreated your process).

If your activity (or process) is killed by Android and the user later navigates back to your activity, Android uses the information it has in its internal data structures to create a new instance of the activity. It then calls `onCreate()` on the new instance passing the saved instance state `Bundle` as a parameter. This can then be used to restore the activity to the state it had before the original instance was killed. Android will also call `onRestoreInstanceState()` after calling `onStart()` so that you can also do your restoration of state in that method if you don't want to do it in `onCreate()`.

Note: Remember that anything you want to save/restore in a `Bundle` must be either a primitive (`int`, `boolean`, etc.) or it must implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

[The documentation of `onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) contains some useful information about this as well.

Comment: many thanks for this deatiled inlut,would you be able to improve your answer by adding how it works internally , please refer to Renan's answer and commnets

Comment: Will do, but I can't do it now. Will try to come back to this later today. Sorry.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127984/activity-record-object-android/18129703?noredirect=1#18129703 give little sense what actually happening in a higher level, good to have bit more idea about its low level behaviour

Comment: many thanks for improving the answer. But I found one statement that would worth to correct , "Your activity's private member variables and static variables are not automatically saved and restored," here "static" variables are retained till the process ends hence should be available regardless the cycle of create/destroy of Activity instances , please refer to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/OHVV4wEbOMs

Comment: So at what point or based on what criteria OS desides to reclaim memory that is used to retain Activity's state I.e "a copy of the Intent that started the activity, the most recent Intent sent to that activity and it keeps a Bundle containing the saved state of that activity"

Comment: As far as I know, the OS never reclaims memory that is used to retain activity state. Since this information is all in `Bundles`, it is all serializable, meaning that it is just a stream of bytes and the OS doesn't need to keep it in memory (it could, if it wanted to, just write the byte stream to a file and read it back later). Android only keeps state for active activities though. Once an activity is "finished", Android no longer retains state for that activity.

Comment: Android keeps a ton of information about what goes on inside the device. Retaining activity state is only a small part of this. To get an idea of what the OS keeps track of, use 'adb shell dumpsys'.

Answer (score 0):

The state is stored, but the activity is destroyed to save memory. So, when the user is in an Activity A and  goes to the Activity B, the Activity A is destroyed, but the state is stored. When the user presses the back button, the state will be loaded and everything will be restored.

The system does it when the activity call onStop and onStart. I didn't make any test, I'm just saying what I understood.

Comment: "state" I assume you meant Bundle object associate with an Activity , so that means in memory run-time keep list of Bundle objects associated to each Activity and when onDestroy of an Activity only the Activity memory block is claimed but associated Bundle would be retained ?

Comment: Yeap, it's what I got. Even I think they don't associate the Bundle with the Activity object, but with some Activity ID, I think...

Comment: This isn't correct. When a user goes from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB`, Android will not destroy `ActivityA` unless that activity is **finished**. The `Activity` class provides the methods `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to deal with saving and restoring the state of the activity. As the documentation indicates, the default implementation of these methods handles saving and restoring the state of all the activities `View`s. This has nothing to do with `onStop()` or `onStart()`.