# What is "activity record object" in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I was referring to following article to further understand the life cycle of the activity and found phrase "activity record object"

Quoting article :

> When your activity is stashed, an Activity object does not exist, but
>   **the activity record object** lives on in the OS.The OS can reanimate the
>   activity using **the activity record** when it needs to.
>
> ---
>
> When onSaveInstanceState(...) is called, the data is saved to the
>   Bundle object.That Bundle object is then **stuffed into your activity's
>   activity record by the OS**

Could any one define exactly what is meant  by **"activity record object"**, and does OS save considerable amount of memory by just killing an activity ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote the passage you quote here (it's from the book [Brian Hardy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209022/lyricsboy) and I wrote, [Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321804333)). Let me see if I can answer your questions.

The "activity record object" (I usually say "activity record") is not visible to you as an application developer. Instead, it lives in the Android OS, where it is used to keep track of your activity. That object is where your saved instance state is stored; it's where the intent that initially started your activity lives, where the activity results you receive are stored before they are delivered. More importantly, if the activity record is alive, it may be used to reconstitute an Activity instance in your application.

The activity record object is much cheaper to keep alive than an instance of the Activity class. An Activity instance has a whole view hierarchy, which can easily take up a few megabytes of memory by itself. On top of that, Activity instances require your app's process to exist. So if there are no Activity instances left, Android can get rid of your entire process, too.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. It almost clear to me but have few questions based on your answer, 1)in 02_MVC_GeoQuiz e.g I can see there is an array TrueFalse[] mAnswerKey tied to the activity , so such state are recorded in " "activity record object" or it is needed to explicitly add into saved instance state ? 2) is there any reference for this information you have taken from?

Comment: 1- That static value only lives in your code (like many things do). And that's okay - it is good to minimize the amount of stuff that Android stashes for your activity. 2- The name "activity record" and a lot of the inspiration for that explanation came from reading the Android source. You will not find any similar explanation in the Android documentation, though. (We found the Android documentation's explanation of the different ways in which an activity may be "alive" somewhat lacking.)

Comment: @BillPhillips Is there one activity record per application? Or do applications share an activity record?

Comment: There is one activity record per activity, from the standpoint of the user. It is associated with Activity instances in your application, so no — applications will never share an activity record.